# uvfs compile issue implicit declaration of function kfree decrement of read-only member i_nlink

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, teamsite

I'm having issue with compiling UVFS on Linux server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago) ) When i'm going to compile it's getting below error

system info:
 uvfs 2.0.7

```
[root@blp033556 uvfs_2.0.7]# gmake

gmake -C /lib/modules/3.8.13-35.el6uek.x86_64/build SUBDIRS=/iwinstall/uvfs_2.0.7 modules
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.8.13-35.el6uek.x86_64'
  CC [M]  /iwinstall/uvfs_2.0.7/dir.o
/iwinstall/uvfs_2.0.7/dir.c: In function uvfs_create:
/iwinstall/uvfs_2.0.7/dir.c:87: error: implicit declaration of function kfree
/iwinstall/uvfs_2.0.7/dir.c: In function uvfs_unlink:
/iwinstall/uvfs_2.0.7/dir.c:221: error: decrement of read-only member i_nlink
/iwinstall/uvfs_2.0.7/dir.c: In function uvfs_mkdir:
```

As we suspect it was compilation issue.  implicit declaration of function kfree and  decrement of read-only member i_nlink issue

could you please help any infomation welcome .

Comment: Did you try to resolve errors by yourself? Using `kfree` requires including `<linux/slab.h>`. The second error means that code attempts to decrement `const` field of the structure.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment i never touch Linux kernel file ,you mean we have to include or modify  slab.h file ? (/usr/src/kernels/3.8.13-35.el6uek.x86_64/include/linux/ slab.h)